# How to output some files from FinalBuilder to teamcity as artifacts

Tags: teamcity, artifacts, finalbuilder

I am using finalbuilder to build my projects and create a package for deployment and I want FinalBuilder to output this package as an artifact to teamcity. I am not sure if this is posible though.

The reason for using finalbuilder to create the package is,in the process of packaging I need to exclude certain files and copy binaries from one project another project etc and the package itself is a collection of mutliple projects. So if I want to specify these as artifact paths in teamcity I will probably end up specifying a number of patterns.

So it would be pretty good if the package created by finalbuilder can be exported to teamcity as artifact.

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"General Settings" of project configuration contains an "Artifact paths" edit area where you can specify what files generated by the build considered "build artifacts".

Or do you mean FinalBuilder consumes other build artifacts?

Comment: Yes,I know it can be set in the General Settings-> Artifact Paths in teamcity. But thing is that I need to specify a number of artifact patterns and I will probably end up with around 30-40 patterns. Instead I am looking for a simple way of doing it.

Comment: I see. Could your patterns be less specific and more general so there will be fewer of them?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. It is pretty difficult to make the patterns less specific.That is why I am looking for an alternate.